# Plotting a circle and filling

Tags: plotting

So I'm brand new to Mathematica and apologise about how simple this problem may seem to this community.

I'm trying to plot a circle and fill its interior. For some reason I can't get Circle or Disk to output, but that's not terribly important. When trying ContourPlot, the axes make a box rather than intersecting in the middle so I find no use with it. I've plotted the desired circle in ParameterPlot but can't seem to fill it with a colour.

What would be the easiest way for me to plot a circle on intersecting axes and fill it with a colour of my choice?

Comment: try `Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]`?

Comment: plenty of options to control the axes in  `CoutourPlot` too. `AxesOrigin` , etc.  mathematica's documentation is really quite good, you need to get in the habit of expanding details sections for every function you use.